# Can a set of vectors in $R^n$ be a subspace of $R^{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to check if a set of vectors with $n$ entries are a subspace of $R^n$.  But when considering sets of vectors that are subspaces of $R^{n+1}$, I would assume that the vectors would have to satisfy the same properties AND be of length $n+1$ instead of length $n$.  So am I correct by inferring that any set of vectors in $R^n$ is NOT a subspace of $R^{n+1}$ because the set is one dimension less than the parent space?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is not even a subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ because, as you noted, the vectors in the two spaces are of different lengths. However, $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ contains many subspaces which are *isomorphic* to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Bungo thanks for the clarification

Comment: To add on, the injective linear transformations $T:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ correspond to ways of viewing the former as a subspace of the latter.